# How to auto-generate passwords in Rails Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying out how Devise works with one of my projects for user authentication. There is a user requirement that their admin should be able to generate a batch of username and user's password from time to time, and then the admin will email the new username and password to his users.

Assume the admin has the knowledge of direct SQL on the MySQL database, how can the generated usernames/passwords recognized by Devise? Thanks!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the [`Devise.friendly_token`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/18b6064d74726147eccd69b24812000074261bbb/lib/devise.rb#L468) method:

```
password_length = 6
password = Devise.friendly_token.first(password_length)
User.create!(:email => 'someone@something.com', :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)
```

FYI: `Devise.friendly_token` returns a 20 character token. In the example above, we're chopping off the first `password_length` characters of the generated token by using the [`String#first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-first) method that Rails provides.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using `devise-security` gem and have specefic `password_complexity` requirements as follows:

`config.password_complexity = { digit: 1, lower: 1, upper: 1 }`

If you use this code: `Devise.friendly_token.first(password_length)` to generate the password, you are not always guaranteed to get a password that matches your complexity.

So I wrote a password generator that will respect your `password_complexity` and will generate a random complaint password:

```
class PasswordGenerator
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :password, presence: true, 'devise_security/password_complexity': Devise.password_complexity
  attr_reader :password

  def initialize
    @password = Devise.friendly_token.first(Devise.password_length.first) until valid?
  end
end
```

You can use it as follows:

`PasswordGenerator.new.password # "qHc165ku"`

Comment: since [nov 16, 2021](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/commit/4f146efe9911debc05f9ce5c99e08f15ab2af61e), devise-security's validator does not complain about empty passwords. so, i had to add `validates :password, presence: true` as well or else `@password` would be `nil` as `valid?` will be `true`.

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to use the Devise.generate_token. I.e.

```
password = User.generate_token('password')
User.create!(:email => 'someone@something.com', :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)
```

This option has not been available in Devise for quite a while. Please refer to the other answer (friendly_token).

Comment: This no longer seems to work in the latest version. I'm getting a 'protected method' error for generate_token.

Comment: You'll want to use `Devise.token_generator` at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

(quick caveat: I'm a rails newb)

I tried the generate_token but it doesn't do what you think (look at the docs)

(I'm using rails 3.0.5, and devise 1.1.7)

What I found is that Devise will generate all that stuff for you in the background when you do:

```
User.create!(:email => "me@example.com", :password => "password")
```

Devise should create the encrypted_password, and salt for you. (pop open a console and try it out there)

Comment: The OP was asking how to "generate" new passwords automatically for new users. What you're doing here is setting every new user's password to "password". Sure it's encrypted in the database, but you're going to be super vulnerable to dictionary (guessing) attacks. If you instead generate unique passwords using tokens (I.e. generate_token) you're extremely secure since these tokens are rather long and complicated (mixed character types, not dictionary based, etc.).

Comment: It looks to me like he's asking how he can input generated usernames and passwords, and have them handled by Devise.  He specifically asks: "how can the generated usernames/passwords recognized by Devise?" which I took to mean: We've already got a generated list of usernames and passwords, but I don't know how to get that info inserted into the database so that devise will recognize it.  What I'm showing above is simply that all the background encryption and such will be handled by Devise, no need to go through the backend DB.

Comment: And I was __definitely__ **NOT** suggesting that they use "password" for every new user.  Hope that's not the way it came across.  That is indeed an incredibly poor way of adding new users.  I originally thought that the 'generate_token' was for generating the encrypted_password, since the OP was hinting at having direct access to the DB (bypassing ActiveRecord all together).

Comment: Agreed. Wasn't very clear. The generate token method is probably most often used to generate one-time authentication parameters (like for invitations). By ensuring it's unique you can essentially give someone a url like http://some.url.com?authentication_token=4hT62wba98s1kfd and have your controller log them in automatically by querying on the token string.