# Ability for users to sign up via SMS (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, ruby-on-rails-5, twilio-api

I am working on a rails application where the main user model is authenticable by mobile number and a password. This all works fine through the website.

What I would like to do is enable a user to access all the same functions of the web app using solely an old school cell phone - that is purely via SMS. I have already enabled some of the web app functions via SMS using Twilio but I was unsure how to go about handling the creation of a user password via SMS in a secure manner.

What I would like:

1. User sends the word "LOAN" to our Twilio number.
2. This creates an account on our system based on their mobile_number. However, a password is required in order to persist a user in the DB so this will need to also be generated here.
3. An SMS is sent to the user with their password in a secure manner.

I imagine my TwilioController action will look something like this:

```
def sign_up
  if params["Body"] == "LOAN"
    user = User.create(mobile_number: params["From"], password: __?__)
    user.sms_sign_up # method to send the sms to the user
  else
    send_failure_sms(params["From"])
  end
end
```

I am already familiar with how to set this up on my Twilio account using TwiML apps - I am only interested in understanding how to manage the password aspect of this problem! Thanks

EDIT: I have seen that Devise provides the method #friendly_token. Is this something that would be useful in this case?

Comment: You can generate a token and send it to the user's phone. Then the user should fill in that code to complete the signup process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think your edit is the answer! I've found other [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681827/how-to-auto-generate-passwords-in-rails-devise) that advocate the use of `Devise.friendly_token` as well as this [How to on generating passwords in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Automatically-generate-password-for-users-(simpler-registration)).

Comment: Thanks phil. I have another question for you which may provoke some discussion but here it goes anyway.
Is it possible to use multiple TwiML apps on the Twilio programmable SMS of a particular number? Cause on my trial account I can only select one of my TwiML apps at a time

Comment: What do you want to do with multiple TwiML apps? Can you not perform all the actions you need using one endpoint that your TwiML app points to?

Comment: Seems I have a tendency to figure out the answer just before you reply each time haha! I did just that, used one entry point and routed to different actions depending on the body of the sms message.
I also need users to fill in a lot of information but am unsure if there is a good way to do this by text/voice (targeting people who only use cell phones). Do you have any guidance for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I can fit a good answer to that in this comment box! Want to drop me an email, philnash@twilio.com, with a few more details and I'll try to get back to you.